# How do I locate all of the JavaScript that affects the CSS in a huge JavaScript document really fast?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am in a situation where I must analyze the code of a website using the inspector tool and find the root cause of issues that happen.

One thing that happens is that a CSS class in the code is being manipulated by Javascript. There are 20+ scripts being linked to site pages plus some code is written inline.

I have to search all the Javascript to find the Jvascript that affects the CSS class or CSS id which requires me to control+F search through 20+ different documents.

Is there a more effective way of doing this?

What are your suggestions on what I should do to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hook into the JavaScript that manipulates CSS, make it work for you. I can't give you specifics because your question lacks useful info, see this section on [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio Code, you can search for the word you want to search in all files with Windows - Ctrl + SHIFT + F / Mac - Command + Shift + F key combination.

If you are searching with a browser, when you open DevTools, go to the network tab and click the search icon. You can search by typing the word you want in the search box on the left window.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way. Here are the steps you should take:

1. Check the console. There might be some information there.
2. If you didn't find anything, follow the next steps.
3. Right click the page and click "View Source"
4. Try using Ctrl+F or Cmd+F to find all the scripts.
5. Open all scripts in a new tab. You should save analytics and other scripts to the end when you checked the others.
6. In those scripts, find the name of the class name or element that is being modified, and that code is probably what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You want a tool like "grep" for the platform you're working on. There's ample implementations for Windows, and ofcourse unix/linux - where it lives natively. Don't know about other platforms but a simple google "grep for ***" should help you  out there.

Grep allows you to search specific strings in text-documents on your filesystem. If you know regex: even better.

Look for the code/classes that give you issues in your debugger, then look for the string that calls the class on your filesystem. Grep will return all files with that string and probably give you some options to preview

Check it out and good luck!!